# How do I apply physics on moving Ball which Collide with non moving ball - AndEngine

Tags: android, andengine, collision

I'm creating Demo application in which 2 Ball one is moving and one is static (Not moving) . I just want to **collide** both of them at run time. but my moving object not moving when i apply **update position true** in this line of code:

> this.mPhysicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(ball, body, false, true));

here is my code

```
public class DizyBall extends SimpleBaseGameActivity implements IOnSceneTouchListener {
// ===========================================================
// Constants
// ===========================================================

private static final int CAMERA_WIDTH = 740;
private static final int CAMERA_HEIGHT = 480;

private static final float DEMO_VELOCITY = 150.0f;

// ===========================================================
// Fields
// ===========================================================
private Scene mScene;
private PhysicsWorld mPhysicsWorld;
private Body body;
private FixtureDef objectFixtureDef ;
private BitmapTextureAtlas mBitmapTextureAtlas;
private TiledTextureRegion mFaceTextureRegion;
private TextureRegion mColiTextureRegion;

// ===========================================================
// Constructors
// ===========================================================

// ===========================================================
// Getter & Setter
// ===========================================================

// ===========================================================
// Methods for/from SuperClass/Interfaces
// ===========================================================

@Override
public EngineOptions onCreateEngineOptions() {
    final Camera camera = new Camera(0, 0, DizyBall.CAMERA_WIDTH, DizyBall.CAMERA_HEIGHT);

    return new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE_FIXED, new RatioResolutionPolicy(DizyBall.CAMERA_WIDTH, DizyBall.CAMERA_HEIGHT), camera);
}

@Override
public void onCreateResources() {
    BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.setAssetBasePath("gfx/");

    this.mBitmapTextureAtlas = new BitmapTextureAtlas(this.getTextureManager(), 48, 48, TextureOptions.BILINEAR);
    this.mFaceTextureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createTiledFromAsset(this.mBitmapTextureAtlas, this, "ball.png", 0, 0, 1, 1);
    this.mColiTextureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(this.mBitmapTextureAtlas, this, "ball.png",0,0);

    this.mBitmapTextureAtlas.load();
}

@Override
public Scene onCreateScene() {
    this.mEngine.registerUpdateHandler(new FPSLogger());


    mScene = new Scene();
    mScene.setBackground(new Background(0.09804f, 0.6274f, 0.8784f));
    mScene.setOnSceneTouchListener(this);


    objectFixtureDef = PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(1, 0.5f, 0.5f);

    this.mPhysicsWorld = new FixedStepPhysicsWorld(30, new Vector2(0, 0), false, 3, 2);

    final float centerX = (DizyBall.CAMERA_WIDTH - this.mFaceTextureRegion.getWidth()) / 2;
    final float centerY = (DizyBall.CAMERA_HEIGHT - this.mFaceTextureRegion.getHeight()) / 2;

    final Sprite Coli = new Sprite(centerX, centerY, this.mColiTextureRegion, this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
    body = PhysicsFactory.createCircleBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, Coli, BodyType.DynamicBody, objectFixtureDef);
    this.mPhysicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(Coli, body, true, true));


    mScene.attachChild(Coli);
    this.mScene.registerUpdateHandler(this.mPhysicsWorld);
    return mScene;
}

// ===========================================================
// Methods
// ===========================================================


@Override
public boolean onSceneTouchEvent(Scene pScene, TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent) {

  //        pSceneTouchEvent
    if(this.mPhysicsWorld != null) {
        if(pSceneTouchEvent.isActionUp()){
            final Ball ball = new Ball(pSceneTouchEvent.getX(), pSceneTouchEvent.getY(), this.mFaceTextureRegion, this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());



            body = PhysicsFactory.createCircleBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, ball, BodyType.DynamicBody, objectFixtureDef);

            this.mScene.attachChild(ball);
            this.mPhysicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(ball, body, false, true));
            return false;
        }
    }else{
        Log.v("PhysicsWorld","NULL");
    }

    return false;
}
// ===========================================================
// Inner and Anonymous Classes
// ===========================================================

private static class Ball extends AnimatedSprite {
    private final PhysicsHandler mPhysicsHandler;

    public Ball(final float pX, final float pY, final TiledTextureRegion pTextureRegion, final VertexBufferObjectManager pVertexBufferObjectManager) {
        super(pX, pY, pTextureRegion, pVertexBufferObjectManager);
        this.mPhysicsHandler = new PhysicsHandler(this);
        this.registerUpdateHandler(this.mPhysicsHandler);
        this.mPhysicsHandler.setVelocity(DizyBall.DEMO_VELOCITY, DizyBall.DEMO_VELOCITY);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onManagedUpdate(final float pSecondsElapsed) {
        if(this.mX < 0) {
            this.mPhysicsHandler.setVelocityX(DizyBall.DEMO_VELOCITY);
        } else if(this.mX + this.getWidth() > DizyBall.CAMERA_WIDTH) {
            this.mPhysicsHandler.setVelocityX(-DizyBall.DEMO_VELOCITY);
        }

        if(this.mY < 0) {
            this.mPhysicsHandler.setVelocityY(DizyBall.DEMO_VELOCITY);
        } else if(this.mY + this.getHeight() > DizyBall.CAMERA_HEIGHT) {
            this.mPhysicsHandler.setVelocityY(-DizyBall.DEMO_VELOCITY);
        }

        super.onManagedUpdate(pSecondsElapsed);
    }
}
 }
```

**Bellow is the Image at run time but both are not Collide.**
[image]

Comment: It touch when i comment this line : this.registerUpdateHandler(this.mPhysicsHandler); means it will not moving .. :/

Comment: It looks like, you didnt do much research before putting a bounty on this question.

Comment: I used elastic 1 so it bounce same rate and I tried body.setLinearVelocity(10,10); too. but because of gravity it not moving well mean not going angular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add this line after mScene.registerUpdateHandler(this.mPhysicsHandler);

```
mScene.registerUpdateHandler(this);
```

Then implement the updatehandler and add the unimplemented methods, now you can do anything in the onUpdate method, like

```
body.setLinearVelocity(10,10);
```

to make it collide with the other object.

Comment: You can check out the AndEngine examples. Or you can tell me whats going wrong NOW and I'll help you out.

Comment: The first boolean is for enabling the movement and the second is for enabling the rotation. Did you do anything to move the ball? Like apply force on it or set velocity to it?

Comment: You dont set Linear Velocity to the Physics Handler, you set it to the body directly. It looks like you didnt write the code yourself, I strongly recommend you to take a look at the examples first : https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngineExamples.

Comment: Hi,I got the solution..prob was gravity which I want to make 0. so only 1 more line needed there. mPhysicsWorld.setGravity(new Vector2()); Nd it's works :) Now I'm working on , moving the ball where clicked/Touched .. If you have Idea then .. :)

Comment: Well if you'd told me the trouble with gravity, I would've helped you earlier. Anyway its always good to play around with your code and figure things out yourself. By the way, you're welcome :)